# jQuery onfocus of an element have another element clickable

Tags: jquery, css, forms, event-handling, css-selectors

I am trying to make a input field with an adjacent dropdown list, the idea is that an input field can either accept text input by the user or a value selected from the dropdown list. To make things as simple as possible I was using styles to queue in on when the input has `focus` then showing the dropdown list. The problem is that when an item is clicked the input loses focus and the dropdown goes away making it impossible to detect the click action.

Is there a simple way around this? Ideally I would like to keep things the way they are I am wondering more if there is a different way I can listen for the click to populate the form field? Code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery editable select</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<style>
.wrap { width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .left { width: 600px; float: left; }
    .right { width: 400px; float: right; }

.editable-select-wrap {}
    .editable-input {}
        .editable-input:focus + .editable-drop { display: block; }
    .editable-drop { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #eee; display: none; }
        .editable-drop.focus { display: block; }
        .editable-drop li { display: block; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; cursor: pointer; }
            .editable-drop li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">

    <div class="left">

        <span class="editable-select" data-name="phone" data-options='[{"val" : "1","text" : "Option 1"}, {"val" : "2","text" : "Option 2"}]'></span>

    </div>
    <div class="right">

        <span class="editable-select" data-name="message" data-options='[{"val" : "1","text" : "Option 1"}, {"val" : "2","text" : "Option 2"}]'></span>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
( function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.editableSelect = function( options ) {

        /*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Configuration Settings    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%*/
        var config = $.extend({
            bootstrap: false,
            classDefault : 'editable-input',
            classbootstrap: 'form-control'
        }, options );

        var html = classes = '', json;

        if( config.bootstrap ) {
            classes = config.classbootstrap +' '+ config.classDefault;
        } else {
            classes = config.classDefault;
        }

        $( this ).each( function() {

            html = '';

            html = '<div class="editable-select-wrap">';
                html += '<input type="text" name="'+ $( this ).data('name') +'" class="'+ classes +'" />';
                html += '<ul class="editable-drop">';

            json = $( this ).data('options' );

            $( json ).each( function() {
                html += '<li data-value="'+ this.val +'">'+ this.text +'</li>';
            });

            html += '</ul></div>';

            $( this ).html( html );
        });

        var parent;

        $('body').on('click', '.editable-drop li', function() {
console.log( 'fire' );
            parent = $( this ).parent();

            parent.siblings('input').val( $( this ).text() );

            parent.css('display', 'none');

        });

    };

}) ( jQuery );

$('.editable-select').editableSelect({ bootstrap: true });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is a fiddle for the code, I removed the bootstrap assets:

http://jsfiddle.net/godoploid/m6sdgyr1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this by adding a `hover` to `editable-drop`

```
.editable-drop:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xL1kbfne/1/

Or Code Snippet Below:

```js
( function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.editableSelect = function( options ) {

        /*%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    Configuration Settings    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%*/
        var config = $.extend({
            bootstrap: false,
            classDefault : 'editable-input',
            classbootstrap: 'form-control'
        }, options );

        var html = classes = '', json;

        if( config.bootstrap ) {
            classes = config.classbootstrap +' '+ config.classDefault;
        } else {
            classes = config.classDefault;
        }

        $( this ).each( function() {

            html = '';

            html = '<div class="editable-select-wrap">';
                html += '<input type="text" name="'+ $( this ).data('name') +'" class="'+ classes +'" />';
                html += '<ul class="editable-drop">';

            json = $( this ).data('options' );

            $( json ).each( function() {
                html += '<li data-value="'+ this.val +'">'+ this.text +'</li>';
            });

            html += '</ul></div>';

            $( this ).html( html );
        });

        var parent;

        $('body').on('click', '.editable-drop li', function() {
console.log( 'fire' );
            parent = $( this ).parent();

            parent.siblings('input').val( $( this ).text() );

            parent.css('display', 'none');

        });

    };

}) ( jQuery );

$('.editable-select').editableSelect({ bootstrap: true });
```

```css
.wrap { width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .left { width: 600px; float: left; }
    .right { width: 400px; float: right; }

.editable-select-wrap {}
    .editable-input {}
        .editable-input:focus + .editable-drop { display: block; }
    .editable-drop { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #eee; display: none; }
        .editable-drop.focus { display: block; }
        .editable-drop li { display: block; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; cursor: pointer; }
            .editable-drop li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }

    .editable-drop:hover {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="left">

        <span class="editable-select" data-name="phone" data-options='[{"val" : "1","text" : "Option 1"}, {"val" : "2","text" : "Option 2"}]'></span>

    </div>
    <div class="right">

        <span class="editable-select" data-name="message" data-options='[{"val" : "1","text" : "Option 1"}, {"val" : "2","text" : "Option 2"}]'></span>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sweet thank you!, its strange adding a hover to the syntax made the difference but it did! Thanks again!!!

Comment: @TomBird well it is because now that we have a hover effect and you are unfocusing the textbox, you are now infact hovering so it will keep the `display:block` instead of returning it to `display:none`.  Therefore you can now click the Options.  Your welcome, have a good one!